# Prove that $E[n_i^2] = 2-\frac{1}{n}$

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, algorithms, expected-value

Before explaining the problem, I'll try to give some context, the context only serves to understand where the problem fits. The real question is purely algebraic and concerns an equality that I cannot justify. The question is therefore inserted in a precise point of the proof:
In the [book](https://sd.blackball.lv/library/Introduction_to_Algorithms_Third_Edition_(2009).pdf) "Introduction to Algorithms" by Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest, and Stein. In chapter 8, when dealing with the cost analysis of the BUCKET-SORT algorithm, the following statements are made:

> To analyze the cost of the calls to insertion sort, let $n_i$ be the random variable
> denoting the number of elements placed in bucket B[i]. Since insertion sort runs
> in quadratic time (see Section 2.2), the running time of bucket sort is

$T(n) = Θ(n)+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{O(n_i^2)} $

> We now analyze the average-case running time of bucket sort, by computing the
> expected value of the running time, where we take the expectation over the input
> distribution. Taking expectations of both sides and using linearity of expectation,
> we have

$$E[T(n)] = E[ Θ(n)+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{O(n_i^2)} ] \overset{\text{(by linearity of expectation)}}{=} Θ(n)+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{E[O(n_i^2)]} = Θ(n)+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{O(E[n_i^2])} $$

> We claim that
> $$E[n_i^2] = 2 -\frac{1}{n}   \text{ this is the equation we want to prove, which in the book is denoted by(8.2)}$$ for i = $0,1,...,n$. It is no surprise that each bucket i has the same value of
> $E[n_i^2]$, since each value in the input array A is equally likely to fall in any bucket.
> To prove equation (8.2), we define indicator random variables

$X_{ij} = I({A[j] \text{ falls in bucket i }})$

> for $i = 0,1,...,n-1$ and $j = 1,2,...n$. Thus,

$n_i = \sum_{j=i}^n{X_{ij}}$

> To compute $E[n_i^2]$, we expand the square and regroup terms:

$E[n_i^2] = E[( \sum_{j=1}^n{X_{ij}} )^2] = E[\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n{X_{ij}X_{ik}}] \overset{\text{(How is this equality algebraically justified?)}}{=} E[\sum_{j=1}^n{X_{ij}^2}+\sum_{1≤j≤n}\sum_{1≤k≤n, k≠j}{X_{ij}X_{ik}}] \overset{\text{(equation8.3)}}{=} \sum_{j=1}^n{E[X_{ij}^2]}+\sum_{1≤j≤n}\sum_{1≤k≤n, k≠j}{E[X_{ij}X_{ik}]}$

> where the last line follows by linearity of expectation. We evaluate the two summations separately. Indicator random variable $X_{ij}$ is 1 with probability 1=n and 0
> otherwise, and therefore

$E[x_{ij}^2] = 1^2\frac{1}{n} + 0^2 (1-\frac{1}{n}) = \frac{1}{n}$

> When $k≠j$, the values $X_{ij}$ and $X_{ik}$ are independent, and hence

$E[X_{ij}X_{ik}] = E[X_{ij}] E[X_{ik}] = \frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{n^2}$

> Substituting these two expected values in equation (8.3), we obtain

$E[n_i^2] = \sum_{j=1}^n\frac{1}{n}+\sum_{1≤j≤n}\sum_{1≤k≤n, k≠j}{\frac{1}{n^2}} = n\frac{1}{n} +  n(n-1)\frac{1}{n^2} = 1+ \frac{n-1}{n} = 2-\frac{1}{n}$

> which proves equation (8.2).

Comment: What is your question? How the final displayed equation is derived?

Comment: The LHS of the equality you point out is summing over pairs $(j,k)$. The RHS is just splitting that sum into two parts: one for the case $j=k$ (hence $k$ is also denoted $j$ now) and one for the case $j \ne k$. It's just rearranging terms. Look at a simple case like $n=3$ and check that the same terms are present on both sides of the equation, if you're uncomfortable with this.